# I want to search for file and assign content to a variable with the libary of tkinter

Tags: python, file, tkinter, search, assign

I want to use tkinter for a simple file search and assign the content to a matrix y for example because the file has numbers in it which I need. I browsed a little bit and found this code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd 

def callback():
    name= fd.askopenfilename() 
    print(name)
    
errmsg = 'Error!'
tk.Button(text='Click to Open File', 
       command=callback).pack(fill=tk.X)
tk.mainloop()
```

I could search for the file but didnt give me the expected output. It just gave me the path of the file which I dont need.
I tried something with read() but it did not work.

Does somebody has a simple code for searching a file and assign the content or any tipps?
I appreciate every answer :)

Comment: There is no code on reading the file content and search for something. Better provide sample data of the file and what you want to *search*.

Comment: @acw1668 so it is not possible to search for a file in the explorer and give a variable the content? It should be similiar to ` y = np.genfromtxt('test.txt')` without a specific txt-data inserted.

Comment: If you have tried using `numpy` to load the text file, then you should show what you have tried and state what the problem you came across.

Comment: It worked! I combined both and replaced 'test.txt'  in genfromtxt() with name. @acw1668 thank you for the tipp.